# Themes in meteor

Tags: themes, meteor

I am working on a project that requires a public frontend (with some sections for members only), an admin area & mobile app. I would like to use 1 bootstrap theme for frontend, 1 admin bootstrap theme for admin & meteor ionic project for app. How can I do this in 1 project? #meteorjs

Comment: no..not yet..but I guess your updated solution will work. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use  differents Templates, and use different CSS for each template,like this.

```
<template name="admin">
<div class="admin">
<!-- Admin Stuff here -->
</div>
</template>

<template name="ionic">
<div class="ionic">
<!-- Ionic Stuff here -->
</div>
</templates>

<template name="members">
<div class="members">
<!-- Members Stuff here -->
<div>
</templates>
```

[Discover Meteor Spacebar Secrets](https://www.discovermeteor.com/blog/spacebars-secrets-exploring-meteor-new-templating-engine/)

[Try Meteor](https://www.meteor.com/try/2)

[Or this Very basic Tutorial About Templates](http://meteortips.com/book/templates/)

**Update**

So if you want to just upload a CSS file to the mobile, try with this.

**First** create a folder inside the project like this

```
packages/mobile
```

**Second** inside the `mobile` folder create this `package.js` file

```
Package.describe({
   summary: "CSS just for the mobile",
});

Package.on_use(function (api) {   
    api.use(['mizzao:bootstrap-3'], ['web.cordova']);
});
```

[Here we are using the mizzao:bootstrap-3 Package](https://atmospherejs.com/mizzao/bootstrap-3)

**third** on console just run meteor add mobile

we are using just mizzao:bootstrap 3 on the mobile app.

**NOTE**: if you don't want to use mizzao bootstrap you can use

`api.addFiles('myCoolCss.ccs', 'web.cordova');` inside the `package.js` and you will use that `.css` you want, more about addFiles [here](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/pack_addFiles)

Comment: True. But it really doesn't do sepration of concerns. Is it possible to load a set of css only on mobile ?